# Span content over two divs

Tags: html, css

I have the following code where I would like the text in the red div to respond/wrap around the yellow box. Is this even possible (ideally without JS)?

```css
#div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#div3 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
p span {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Bonorum has. His ut cibo quas tantas, vis ut probo adhuc definiebas, has at meis debet vulputate. No sed velit essent suavitate,
      <span>overlap me</span> in pro decore ceteros temporibus, usu in odio offendit theophrastus. Mel labore indoctum cu, ad soleat admodum delicatissimi sed, mei viris tritani ullamcorper eu. Ut vim simul aperiam.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <p>Bonorum has. His ut cibo quas tantas, vis ut probo adhuc definiebas, has at meis debet vulputate. No sed velit essent suavitate, in pro decore ceteros temporibus, usu in odio offendit theophrastus. Mel labore indoctum cu, ad soleat admodum delicatissimi
      sed, mei viris tritani ullamcorper eu. Ut vim simul aperiam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really don't think so with this markup :/

Comment: Is there going to be text in the yellow div? I think there might be away to do it if not.

Comment: It would be a Youtube video ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll take more structure, and a fixed top offset, but it can be done:

```css
#div1 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#div2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#div3 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
.post {
    float: right;
    width: .1px;
    height: 100px;
}
.interruptor {
    width: 260px;
    height: 180px;
    left: 20px;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
#div3 .interruptor {
    width: 130px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
 
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div class="post"></div>

        <div class="interruptor">
            <div class="video-container">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e2--l-YX1HU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>Bonorum has. His ut cibo quas tantas, vis ut probo adhuc definiebas, has at meis debet vulputate. No sed velit essent suavitate, in pro decore ceteros temporibus, usu in odio offendit theophrastus. Mel labore indoctum cu, ad soleat admodum delicatissimi
            sed, mei viris tritani ullamcorper eu. Ut vim simul aperiam.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
        <div class="post"></div>

        <div class="interruptor"></div>

        <p>Bonorum has. His ut cibo quas tantas, vis ut probo adhuc definiebas, has at meis debet vulputate. No sed velit essent suavitate, in pro decore ceteros temporibus, usu in odio offendit theophrastus. Mel labore indoctum cu, ad soleat admodum delicatissimi
            sed, mei viris tritani ullamcorper eu. Ut vim simul aperiam.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/aea9ek8y/)**